# How to constrain the weights in tensorflow and redefine how the output is calculated?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm a relative beginner in tensorflow and I am trying to train a very simple model that can learn the 3-input XOR function. Here's my code:

```py
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy

def generate_training_data():
    train_samples = [(0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,1,0), (0,1,1),
                     (1,0,0), (1,0,1), (1,1,0), (1,1,1)]
    train_labels = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
    return np.array(train_labels), np.array(train_samples)

def create_model():
    model = Sequential([
    Dense(units=4, input_shape=(3,), activation='relu'),
    Dense(units=2)
    ])
    return model

if __name__ == "__main__":
    train_labels, train_samples = generate_training_data()
    model = create_model()
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(x=train_samples, y=train_labels, batch_size=8, epochs=10000, verbose=1)
```

I would like to achieve two things:

1. I would like to restrict my weights to positive values only.
2. I would like to define the output predicted by the model to be the difference between the two output nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the two outputs of the second `Dense` with `tf.math.subtract`, and constrain the weights with `tf.keras.constraints`.

Comment: But how do I tell tensorflow to optimize the weights based on the subtracted value and not the individual values at the two outputs ?

Comment: I was thinking you would add a tf.math.subtract as the new last line in your ```Sequential```.

Comment: As I said, I'm relatively new to tensorflow. Can you probably give me an example that with the weight constraints and output subtraction that I build on ?

Comment: def create_model():
        model = Sequential([
        Dense(units=4, input_shape=(3,), activation='relu'),
        Dense(units=2),
 tf.keras.subtract()
        ])
        return model

Comment: I'm new to Tensorflow, too, so I don't know how to use ```tf.keras.constraints```.